# Next Image not taking class properties

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, nextjs-image

I am using Next.js and `next/image` to display images, but the CSS is not working inside it. The image is in SVG format and I have placed it in the public folder. I am using Tailwind CSS along with this.

```
<Image
  className="mt-3"
  data-testid="close-icon"
  src="/CloseIcon.svg"
  alt="Close Nav Bar"
  height="24"
  width="24"
/>
```

I am not sure why it is not working and it is not being reflected in the browser. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Actually, I can replicate the issue. The `next/image` inline styles seem to be overriding the Tailwind margin utility classes.

Comment: I can see it being applied to the component yes.

Answer (score 40):

##### Before Next.js 12.2

Styling the `next/image` component's margins this way doesn't work in older Next.js versions. See relevant [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/22861) for more details.

Internally to the `next/image` component, the `<img>` element and the elements that wrap it have inline styles that override certain values passed through `className`.

As a workaround, you can add a wrapper element and apply the `margin` styling to it instead.

```
<div className="mt-3">
    <Image
        data-testid="close-icon"
        src="/CloseIcon.svg"
        alt="Close Nav Bar"
        height="24"
        width="24"
    />
</div>
```

---

##### From Next.js 12.2

You can use the `next/future/image` component instead. This new component renders a single `<img>` element without any additional wrappers by default, and is no longer constrained by the wrapper's styles override.

You can enable `next/future/image` in `next.config.js`.

```js
module.exports = {
    experimental: {
        images: {
            allowFutureImage: true
        }
    }
}
```

---

##### From Next.js 13

The `next/future/image` component has been converted to [`next/image`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image). Like `next/future/image`, this component renders a single `<img>` element and can be styled directly with `className`/`styles`.

Comment: And more styles for `Image` component can be passed under `className={style.image_style}`. Thanks bro.

Answer (score 12):

Juliomalves's answer is right, but I would prefer:

```
<div className="mt-3" height="24" width="24">
    <Image
        data-testid="close-icon"
        src="/CloseIcon.svg"
        alt="Close Nav Bar"
        layout="fill"
    />
</div>
```

You also can use a little cheat:

```
import {motion} from "framer-motion";

    <motion.img 
      className="mt-3"
      data-testid="close-icon"
      src="/CloseIcon.svg"
      alt="Close Nav Bar"
      height="24"
      width="24">
```

Comment: You might want to put width and height in style since div doesn't take width and height directly `<div style={{ width: 24, height: 24 }}>`

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
<div style='width:104px;height:104px;position:relative;'>
  <Image
    alt='Mountains'
    src='/mountains.jpg'
    layout='fill'
    objectFit='contain'
  />
</div>
```

More on `objectFit` [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

Answer (score -1):

Wrapping the image component in a `div` helps solve the issue for me. I can apply the class name to the `div` and everything works as it should.