# next js automatically adding style to it's element

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have added my logo in navbar and it seems like next js is adding css automatically to that element

Here is what I got on inspecting the element

```
element.style {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    inset: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
    height: 0px;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Where as the style I added was

```
const fav = {
        width: "35px",
        display: "inline",
        marginTop: "-2.3px",
      };

<Image style={fav} width="30rem" height="30rem" src={logo2} alt="Logo" />
```

Any further requirement I will provide

Comment: ```<Image>``` from 'next/image' is the built-in performance optimizations features, that's why you got those CSS style. Please have a look here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization

Comment: and make sure passing numbers in width and height property, i.e. "30" instead of "30rem"

Comment: That's the expected behaviour when using `next/image`, see [Next Image not taking class properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65527407/next-image-not-taking-class-properties) for potential workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

You can read in the documentation about Image component of nextjs and how its applying own styles to the image element

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#style

Maybe you need to move to raw layout mode? :)
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#experimental-raw-layout-mode